# VBS fast loop through lines

Tags: vbscript

I need to loop and permutate through 2000 lines of a text file(which will always increase in size), get the total length, and based on the length, i need to copy the two records to another file.
The problem is that it takes to long to process everything. I am not sure that this is the best approach but any help is appreciated.

```
filename = "Jul2017.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    r1 = f.ReadLine
    Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
        r2 = f.ReadLine
        if len(r1 & r2) > 17 then
           'Do something
        end if
    Loop
Loop

WScript.Echo "Done!"
f.Close
```

---

This should solve the loop nesting problem.

```
filename = "Jul2017.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 1)

For x = 1 to 2000
r1 = f.ReadLine
For z = 1 to 2000
r2 = f.ReadLine
if len(r1 & r2) > 17 then
'Do something
end if
next
next
WScript.Echo "Done!"
f.Close

Input
-----------
TMM87R2
YUU52R7VVB
VLL73IOP3
TMM54Y2
VLL21CSZ
YUU56
VLL71BVR54
...
```

What i need to do:

```
First iteration
TMM87R2 & TMM87R2 < 17 characters ( do nothing )
TMM87R2 & YUU52R7VVB > 17 characters ( copy the lines )
TMM87R2 & VLL73IOP3 etc.
...
TMM87R2 & VLL71BVR54

Second iteration
YUU52R7VVB & TMM87R2
YUU52R7VVB & YUU52R7VVB
...

Until last iteration
VLL71BVR54 & VLL71BVR54
```

Each line should be "placed" next to each line in the file and if the total size is excedes 17 characters,
copy the two records to another file. I know i am looping 2000 times and it is repetitive but the order of records matters.

Comment: I would think the inner loop would end the outer loop after one run through as f will be AtEndOfStream.  Perhaps show sample input & describe what output you want.

Comment: Sorry, I have some issues using the app on my android.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not read the file into an array in memory

This is in VB.NET but should give you a clue

```
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Jul2017.txt")

        Rem Arrays are zero based, and we cant compare the last element with anything so ...
        For first = 0 To lines.Length - 2
            Dim line = lines(first)
            Dim len = line.Length
            For perm = first + 1 To lines.Length - 1
                If lines(perm).Length + len > 17 Then
                    Rem Do Something
                    Console.WriteLine(line & " & " & lines(perm))
                End If
            Next
        Next
```